# Detecting offline and online status in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous

I am building a GWT app and wants to detect whether user has a internet connection or not. 
My main problem is detect internet at the time of making an asynchronous call. 
We are mainly using Chrome browser.

I tried using this:

```
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

if (caught instanceof StatusCodeException
                && ((StatusCodeException) caught).getStatusCode() == 0) {
            return "NoInternetConnnectivity";   
            }
```

But I found that we receive 0 as status code in many other cases apart from internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

This code has been took from the vaadin TouchKit [offline](https://github.com/vaadin/touchkit/blob/master/vaadin-touchkit-agpl/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/touchkit/gwt/client/vcom/OfflineModeConnector.java#L114) implementation, it is the only way to ask the browser whether it is online is using html5. Note that not all browsers support this feature so you have to return true if the attribute does not exist.

```
 private static native boolean isNavigatorOnline()
 /*-{
    if($wnd.navigator.onLine != undefined) {
        return $wnd.navigator.onLine;
    }
    return true;
 }-*/;
```

But, this only works under certain circumstances, and I would say that it is reliable enough only for mobile devices.

If you want to be sure that your server is reachable, I would have a loop in my code to poll the server, I would capture as well all server ajax responses to check whether there is a server failure or a network error. Normally when you get a `Response.getStatusCode == 0` means you couldn't reach your server (network down, server down, CORS error, etc), that IMO is the case you have to consider to warn the user with a message like  `server unreachable, test your connection, ...`

Answer (score 0):

The surest way would be to rely on HTML5's navigator.onLine method. You can add a native method:

```
public static native boolean isOnline() /*-{
        return $wnd.navigator.onLine;
    }-*/;
```

and then use this method in your client side code.

Comment: You can not really rely on _navigator.onLine_. Even the spec says _This attribute is inherently unreliable. A computer can be connected to a network without having Internet access._ See [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/author/offline.html#browser-state)

Comment: @AdrianB. Then do you know any other method to do same ?